# Common File Upload not working

Tags: java, file, file-upload, servlet-3.0

Following is my complete code for uploading file to server using apache common upload. When I test this function in new project, it works. But when I integrated into my project, it's not working anymore. I found the problem in "List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);" fileItems there is zero while it should be 1. Is there some wat that I can solve this issue?

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
               HttpServletResponse response)
              throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {
      // Check that we have a file upload request
      //isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
      response.setContentType("text/html");
      java.io.PrintWriter out = response.getWriter( );
      if( !isMultipart ){
         out.println("<html>");
         out.println("<head>")y
         out.println("<title>Servlet upload</title>");  
         out.println("</head>");
         out.println("<body>");
         out.println("<p>No file uploaded</p>"); 
         out.println("</body>");
         out.println("</html>");
         return;
      }
      DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
      // maximum size that will be stored in memory
      factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);
      // Location to save data that is larger than maxMemSize.
      factory.setRepository(new File("c:\\temp"));

      // Create a new file upload handler
      ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
      // maximum file size to be uploaded.
      upload.setSizeMax( maxFileSize );

      try{ 
      // Parse the request to get file items.
      List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

      // Process the uploaded file items
      Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();

      out.println("<html>");
      out.println("<head>");
      out.println("<title>Servlet upload</title>");  
      out.println("</head>");
      out.println("<body>");
      while ( i.hasNext () ) 
      {
         FileItem fi = (FileItem)i.next();
         if ( !fi.isFormField () )  
         {
            // Get the uploaded file parameters
            String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
            String fileName = fi.getName();
            String contentType = fi.getContentType();
            boolean isInMemory = fi.isInMemory();
            long sizeInBytes = fi.getSize();
            // Write the file
            if( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0 ){
               file = new File( filePath + 
               fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\"))) ;
            }else{
               file = new File( filePath + 
               fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1)) ;
            }
            fi.write( file ) ;
            out.println("Uploaded Filename: " + fileName + "<br>");
         }
      }
      out.println("</body>");
      out.println("</html>");
   }catch(Exception ex) {
       System.out.println(ex);
   }
   }
```

Comment: Does your input type element (type='file') in jsp have a 'name' attribute?

Comment: Try adding it, servlet containers have different specs and tomcat seems to need it.

Comment: What are your values for maxMemSize and maxFileSize?

Comment: I added name attribute and it works. Thanks @PopoFibo

Answer (score 0):

> When I test this function in new project, it works. But when I integrated into my project, it's not working anymore.

That's generally a sign that the library versions are different.  If you're using maven, compare the dependency graphs below the apache common artifact so you can get your test project on the same version.

Comment: I use the same library file on my project.